# i am having problem with this code, i want form not to submit when password field is blank

Tags: jquery

```
var email = $('#email').val();
var pwd = $('#pwd').val();

if (email == 'email' || pwd == 'pwd') {
  //If the two fields are empty

  if (email == 'email') {
    $('#emailerror').html('Please Insert reciever\'s email address');
    $('#response').html('');
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#pwderror').html('Please Insert password');
    $('#response').html('');
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like this:

```
  if (!email.trim() || !pwd.trim()) {
    if (!email.trim()) {
      $('#emailerror').html('Please Insert reciever\'s address');
      $('#response').html('');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#pwderror').html('Please Insert password');
      $('#response').html('');
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more universal solution for the future

```
function isNullOrWhiteSpace(value) {
    if (value === undefined || value === null || value.trim() === "") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function validate(){
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var pwd = $('#pwd').val();

    if(isNullOrWhiteSpace(email) || isNullOrWhiteSpace(pwd)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```